# Camera involentarily listing to the right in Psychonauts

Tags: mouse, games

I've recently purchased the Humble Bundle V and have been having an absolute riot with the games given. The one problem I'm running into though, is that whenever I launch Psychonauts and run a game, the Camera lists to the right slowly and I can't get it to stop.

Strangely enough when I zoom in (with z), it lists to the left.

I was wondering if anyone else had this problem and if there was a solution. Maybe it's even the mouse configs I currently have on the laptop that interacts strangely with 3D environments.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. After a little experimenting I discovered that increasing the deadzone setting cleared it up even though I was using a mouse and not a gamepad.

Comment: this fixed it for me but only until the first video sequence after loading.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would share [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11998256) answer, since it seems to have fixed the problem on some other systems. Basically, disable joystick support like this:

```
sudo rmmod joydev
```

However, this does *not* work for me, hopefully it does for someone else.